# File Not Loaded with gulp-concat

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, gulp-concat

After `gulp-concat`, new concatenated `js` file is added in my project folder and then I start server but file is not loaded in the browser . 
Server responded with 404 .

**Browser Console:**

[image]

**Browser Developer Tool's Application Tab**

[image]

**Gulp File**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.pipe(gulp.dest('views'))`

It looks like you're saving the file to your `views` folder. If that's intentional you will have to load it from `views/main.js`.

Comment: right now i am saving both index and js file in same folder views for testing purposes. And I've also tried as you suggested but it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Have you tried saving it to `public/main.js`? @NiravChavda

Comment: i'm using hbs view engine in this . The file is index.hbs .@Kieran

Comment: thanks for your help . The problem has been solved I just set the static path for js using `app.use('/js',express.static(dirname+'/public/assets/js'));`